# Standard term for instantiation practice

Tags: c#, instantiation, terminology

Is there a standard term for the practice of instantiate a class without using an explicit constructor but instead initializing some of its properties?

```
new SomeClass { PropertyA = true, PropertyB = "ugly code is ugly" };
```

I'm guessing there could be a standard not judgemental term and then there could be a negative term.

** --- ** --- EDITED POST CLARIFYING COMMENTS AND ANSWERS --- *** ---

Object Initialization it is.

After reading the comments I understand object initialization itself is not a bad practice; the problem is the lack of well defined constructors in favor of object initialization spread across a solution, which makes the solution much harder to maintain and to understand.

An example of bad use of object initialization:

- Class `Student` has 10 properties including `Code` and `Program`.
- The code is instantiating this class from 10+ different points.
- Every time, `Code` and `Program` are being defined through object initialization.

In this case, class `Student` should have a constructor enforcing `Code` and `Program` to be passed on instantiation.

Comment: This is an object initializer. That's what it's called, in good times and bad. This *does* use a constructor: the default constructor in this case. And then it assigns some properties. Just like it would if you wrote more code for it. I've never heard anyone being judgemental about it, but no doubt someone has found reason to.

Comment: I suppose author means the difference between doing new SomeClass(true, "ugly code is ugly") and what is shown in question.

Comment: We have no idea if there is such a constructor that can to it like this.

Comment: I updated the question clarifying the negative aspect I was referring to. Question was not properly asked, hence the negative vote I got. Anyway, this helped me to pin point the bad practice I'm facing right now while refactoring old code at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called Object Initialization

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's an object initializer.

I'm not sure what you mean by "negative term". There is nothing wrong with instantiating an object and setting some of its properties in 1 go. Its better than the alternative

```
var someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.PropertyA = true;
someClass.PropertyB = "Clean code is clean";
```

Comment: You are right but I accepted the other one because it came in before. About the negative term thing, I updated the question with comments about that. Thanks for your quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is referred to as "[Initializer Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)"